# angular/browserify: Failed to instantiate module ngResource

Tags: angularjs, browserify

I am testing browserify with angular. I have installed ng-resource to my project:

```
npm install --save ng-resource
```

I am loading it like this:

```
require('angular');
require('ng-resource');
require('angular-ui-router');


var app = angular.module('app.module', ['ngResource']
```

but receive the following error:

```
Failed to instantiate module app.module due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngResource due to..
```

As far as I know I do not have to load ng-resource explicitly when I am using browserify... What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are requiring the correct library? Do you probably mean the official `angular-resource`?

Please compare https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-resource and https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resource

I think the latter is the one to go with. The ng-resource package somehow seems to be a private port which is no longer maintained...

Try installing the `angular-resource` module

```
npm install angular-resource --save
```

and adapt your code as follows:

```
require('angular-resource');
angular.module('app.module', ['ngResource']);
```